# Start Bootstro in the field with focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstro

I am using Bootstro with Bootstrap in my forms. It is working the way it should. But I would like to do something:

When I click in the button to start bootstro, it starts in the first element in the form. I would like to start bootstro in the field i have focus. If I do not have focus in any field, it should start from the beginning.

Thanks.

Comment: Show some code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it. You'd grab the selected input and use that, or a default.

```
var focusedEl = $('input:focus');
var myEl; 

if (focusedEl.length) {
    myEl = focusedEl;
} else {
    myEl = $('#someOtherElement');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    bootstro.start(myEl, options);
});
```